# IMAP migration tool

Tags: backup, mail-server, imap

I currently have several email accounts on 1 domain with a hosting service who runs an IMAP server for me. I'd like to migrate all email accounts to a new server.
I don't know the distro. The server resides on an Digital Ocean droplet. I only have IMAP server details (no ssh/root) to connect to read/send emails. Now I want to migrate. How can I do this? –

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux? Do you make regular backups? Why can't you restore from your backup?

Comment: I don't know the distro. The server resides on an Digital Ocean droplet. I only have IMAP server details (no ssh/root) to connect to read/send emails. Now I want to migrate. How can I do this?

Comment: Add this information to your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [OfflineIMAP](http://www.offlineimap.org/) and Thunderbird to migrate emails from one place to another.

OfflineIMAP is a great command-line tool which can connect to your old IMAP server, and download all the mail to a local directory.

Once completely downloaded, you can connect Thunderbird to your new email provider, and import the mail you've downloaded.

Comment: thanks - so OfflineIMAP cannot upload the emails to my new server?

Comment: I've never tried. In theory, it can "sync", so potentially it can, but I can't comment as I have never done that.